# Can a JSON Schema describe the constrant that an array of arrays must have elements of all the same length?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

Basically, I'm trying to see if a schema can be written that will accept an array of arrays, such that all the inner arrays have the same length as each other. For example, the schema should *accept* the following:

`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

`[[1], [2], [3]]`

`[[1 2 3 4]]`

But reject the following:

`[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`

`[[1 2 3 4 5], [6]]`

Can JSON Schema do this, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think so. Well, I implemented a schema checker for my own code, and I cannot remember any code checking for this :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enforce that nested arrays have a given length by using the `items`, `maxItems` and `minItems` keywords:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "minItems" : 2,
        "maxItems" : 2
    }
}
```

Although you can not (in general) enforce the property that all nested arrays have the same number of elements, if not every length is possible, you may try a brute force approach by using `oneOf`:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "oneOf" : [{
                "type" : "array",
                "minItems" = 1,
                "maxItems" = 1
            }, {
                "type" : "array",
                "minItems" = 2,
                "maxItems" = 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```